# Microsoft BigInteger goes "negative" when I import from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, biginteger, bit-shift, twos-complement

Suppose I have an array that ends with the most signifiant bit of the most significant byte equaling 1.

My understanding is that if this is the case, BigInteger will treat this as a negative number, by design.

```
     BigInteger numberToShorten = new BigInteger(toEncode);

        if (numberToShorten.Sign == -1)
        {
            // problem with twos compliment or the last bit of the last byte is equal to 1
            throw new Exception("Unexpected negative number");
        }
```

To solve this problem, I think I need to add a dummy zero bit to the array, prior to converting the array.  I can easily do this using `Array.Resize()`.

- My question is, how should I test if the last bit is indeed equal to `1`?

I'm pretty weak on my boolean logic now, and am thinking I need to AND the values and test for equality, but not able to get the syntax correct in C#.  Something like this:

```
    byte temp = toEncode[toEncode.Length - 1];

    if (temp == ???)
    {
       Array.Resize(ref toEncode, toEncode.Length +1);
     }
```

Comment: You don't have to check any bits. If you know you're only dealing with positive values,  just prepend a `0` to the string and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

If the number to be converted to `BigInteger` is always positive then you don't actually need to test at all; just appending a zero byte will always work correctly.

For completeness, checking if the MSB of any one byte is set is done with

```
if (byte & 0x80 == 0x80) ...
```

Comment: how do I check the MSB of a byte is == 1?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [at the bottom of this MSDN article (I think)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    ulong originalNumber = UInt64.MaxValue;
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(originalNumber);
    if (originalNumber > 0 && (bytes[bytes.Length - 1] & 0x80) > 0) 
    {
       byte[] temp = new byte[bytes.Length];
       Array.Copy(bytes, temp, bytes.Length);
       bytes = new byte[temp.Length + 1];
       Array.Copy(temp, bytes, temp.Length);
    }

    BigInteger newNumber = new BigInteger(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("Converted the UInt64 value {0:N0} to {1:N0}.", 
                      originalNumber, newNumber); 
    // The example displays the following output: 
    //    Converted the UInt64 value 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.
```

Comment: What you had in the question (`Array.Resize`) is better than what you found here, I think. The check for whether to append zero does look correct, though. And if you don't know if the array could be empty, make sure to check for that before attempting to access `bytes[bytes.Length - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is necessary, have you tried it? In any case, assuming that `temp` contains a byte and you are trying to test whether that byte ends in 1, this is how you should do it:

```
if((temp & 0x01)==1)
{
    ...
}
```

That amounts to:

```
Temp:        ???????z
0x01:        00000001
Temp & 0x01: 0000000z
```

Where z represents the bit you are trying to test, and you can now just test whether the result is equal to 1 or not.

If you are trying to test whether the byte starts with 1, do:

```
if((temp & 0x80)==0x80) //0x80 is 10000000 in binary
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think the bit that counts is the most significant in the byte, not the least significant.